# Why does Thread.Sleep() run before GUI?

Tags: java, swing

First class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (this.getText().equals("?")) {
        this.setText(board.getCard(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]).getFaceValue());
        
        if (!board.saveRowCol(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])) {                
            frame.hideFirstCard();
            this.setText("?");
            
        } else if (board.secondCheck()){
            board.reset();
        }


    }
}
```

---

Second Class:

```
public boolean saveRowCol(int row, int col) {
    boolean result;
    if (first == null) {
        first = new int[]{row, col};
        return true;
    } else {
        second = new int[] {row, col};
        result = compare(first, second);
        return result;
    }
}

public boolean compare(int[] fir, int[]sec) {
    if (!board[fir[0]][fir[1]].getFaceValue().equals(board[sec[0]][sec[1]].getFaceValue())) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
                   
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't setText() be executed before thread.sleep() in order?
Why does Thread.Sleep(500) run before this.setText(board.getCard(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]).getFaceValue());?
And how should I solve this problem?

Comment: It' doesn't "run before" the GUI, it's been executed within the same thread context used by the GUI, so you're blocking, what is known as, the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for, among other things, scheduling repaints.  Instead, you need to devise a workflow which takes advantage of this, like using a Swing `Timer` to trigger a callback at some point in the future, or a `SwingWorker` to perform the long running actions in background thread

Comment: I recommend having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: 'setText' in most GUIs does not mean 'paint the screen right now and make it visible before returning'.